# How to convert SURF Points matrix to double in Matlab

Tags: matlab, surf, knn

I have extracted the `SURF` Points of several images and saved them in a vector. How to convert this victor into `Double` or `Single` type, so it will be easy classified by `KNN`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectsurffeatures.html), `detectSURFFeatures` (and others) returns a [`SURFPoints`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/surfpoints-class.html?refresh=true) object that has a number of properties including the `Location` property which is an M x 2 matrix of points where the columns are X and Y locations.

You can get that information from the result in the following way.

```
surfobj = detectSURFFeatures(data);
points = surfobj.Location;
```